# Owl Carousel is ignoring the items option

Tags: owl-carousel-2

I'm having an issue with owlcarousel. When I use large images with `items:1` everything works well and each slide contains 1 image. But when I use smaller images the `items:1` option is ignored and the images display 4 per slide.

owlcarousel is version 2.3.4 as are the corresponding CSS files.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".news-post-gallery").owlCarousel({
                navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
                autoplay:false,
                items: 1,
                loop:false,
                margin: 10,
                center: true,
                nav: true,
                navText: [
                    "<div>Left</div>",
                    "<div>Right</div>"
                ],
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:1,
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

My first guess is that this is a CSS issue. Mind you even the small images are not that "small", the large images that I used were like half my screen width.

Edit: navText is being ignored as well when small images are used.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was another carousel being initialized targeting the `owl-carousel` class. This ended up initializing the one I needed with the wrong settings. The carousels initializations were coming from different templates so the result was only visible in the source once the page was loaded.

Adding `$(...).owlCarousel('destroy');` before i initialized mine solved the problem.